# Why doesn't this logging setting work for INFO?

Tags: python, logging

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info('good')
logger.warning('bad')
```

It only prints out 'bad', not 'good'. What's the issue of the setLevel(logging.INFO)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never configured handlers, so the logging system is using the ["last resort" handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.lastResort), which defaults to a level of WARNING. Even if the logger levels say to log a message, it won't be handled unless there's a handler configured to handle it.

Run [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) with the settings you want, to perform basic handler configuration.